# Присвоение/удаление класса одному элементу списка по клику на другой элемент

Tags: javascript, html

Итак, не спешите корить меня мол схожих вопросов пруд пруди.
Работаю ныне со списками и задача теперешняя при клике на элемент списка показывать другой, смежный - субэлемент, скрытый по дефолту. При повторном клике - скрывать его. При клике на соседние элементы - возвращать остальные элементы к дефолтному состоянию и работать лишь с текущим элементом, на который производится клик. У меня вышло реализовать все, но по отдельности и проблема - склеить скрипт вместе. От слов к делу:

```js
$(".click-elem").on("click", function() {
  
  var clickId = $(this).attr("data-number");
  // Участок №1
  $("h4").removeClass("active");
  $(clickId).addClass("active");
  // Участок №2
  // var numberFilter = /\d+/g;
  // var elemIndex = clickId.match(numberFilter);
  // var element = document.getElementById(elemIndex);
  // element.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
.list ul li div h4 {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.click-elem {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  visibility: visible !important;
  color: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>
        <p data-number="#0" class="click-elem">First element</p>
        <h4 id="0">This is first subelement</h4>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <p data-number='#1' class="click-elem">Second element</p>
        <h4 id="1">This is second subelement</h4>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <p data-number='#2' class="click-elem">Third element</p>
        <h4 id="2">This is third subelement</h4>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Сейчас скрипт работает корректно лишь отчасти, увы. При клике появляется субэлемент, при клике на иной элемент, предыдущий скрывается и активируется текущий - все хорошо, но что если юзер захочет скрыть текущий субэлемент? Ничего не выйдет. Для этого я допилил существующий скрипт - это участок №2. Но он входит в конфликт с предыдущим кодом и перестает работать теперь уже участок №1. Поэтому часть кода комментирована.
Пол дня ломаю голову - безрезультатно. Помогите пжлст)
Заранее извиняюсь за косноязычие, я старался максимально ясно описать проблему.
Ссылка на пэн: https://codepen.io/Metalspell/pen/WLpqZJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы наверное это имеете ввиду:

```
$(".click-elem").on("click", function() {

  var clickId = $(this).attr("data-number");
  // Участок №1

  if (!$(clickId).hasClass("active")) {
     $("h4").removeClass("active");
     $(clickId).addClass("active");
  } else {
    $(clickId).removeClass("active");
  }

  // Участок №2
  // var numberFilter = /\d+/g;
  // var elemIndex = clickId.match(numberFilter);
  // var element = document.getElementById(elemIndex);
  // element.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

Проверить здесь:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wRdwmW

Comment: Именно! Спасибо. Конечно, глядя теперь на реализацию, думаю, как это я сам не додумался ведь все просто. И тем не менее...